# Pass parameters from sbt-rjs to uglify

Tags: playframework, requirejs, playframework-2.0, sbt, uglifyjs2

I'm using play! 2.5.8 and I'm minifying my JS files with sbt-rjs that uses uglify2 by default. The minification is very basic (the code is still readable) and I want to improve it.

On sbt-uglify's [github page](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-uglify), there is a table of minification options and most of them are off by default.

Is there a way to pass these parameters from the sbt-rjs configuration (in build.sbt or main.js) to uglify2?

Thanks